Interested in a Languages.SE supersite?
I'm considering proposing a site on Area 51:
Would a general Languages.SE supersite (synchronized with the current language sites) be feasible?
Short description of what I have in mind:

An English-language site for learning non-English languages.  It is synchronized with the existing language sites (which remain unchanged).

I think users here may be interested in such a "supersite"; I've seen multiple users here also at Japanese.SE and Korean.SE.
Currently Stack Exchange are harshly closing proposed sites:

Please link to the organization or website organizing this effort:
If you do not yet have a community organized, ready and eager to build your site, please do not submit this proposal.

It's a very high threshold nowadays.  So if you'd want to participate in this site, I need you to...
 !!!
Either here, or at the Area 51 post above.  We'd need to show Stack Exchange that there's a community wanting to "dive in".

I feel that a better way is to have tags which are linked across other sites and show questions from other sites. Chinese character glyph origins are a prime candidate across Chinese and Japanese SE. Algorithms are a good candidate across StackOverflow and Math.SE. You get the idea...

Hmm... the post was deleted by Community with the message " Via /api/posts/delete-related-discussions".  I don't know how to interpret that.

For those interested, it was taken up at Codidact:  https://languages.codidact.com/
